# Single future posts no showing up

Tags: wordpress

I have www.colegiodepsicologos.org.gt in the Proximos Eventos title, it shows future post from the posttype "eventos", but when you click them it shows not found, how do I change that behaivor to show future post in single?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Done!

```
add_filter(‘the_posts’, ‘show_future_posts’);
function show_future_posts($posts){ 
   global $wp_query, $wpdb;
   if(is_single() && $wp_query->post_count ==0){ 
      $posts = $wpdb->get_results($wp_query->request);
   } 
   return $posts;
};
```

Comment: Note that this will also show trashed posts, which you probably don't want to do. See my other answer to restrict this only to future posts: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25941543/1020126

Answer (score 2):

Careful; the answer by Jepser **will also show trashed/deleted posts**, which you probably don't want to show.

This will restrict it only to future posts (tested on WP 3.9.2):

```
add_filter('the_posts', 'show_future_posts');

function show_future_posts($posts)
{
   global $wp_query, $wpdb;

   if(is_single() && empty($posts)) //detect cases where WP usually shows 404
   {
      $posts = $wpdb->get_results($wp_query->request);

      //make sure it only affects future posts, not trashed
      if(isset($posts[0]->post_status)&&$posts[0]->post_status!='future'){
        $posts=array();
      }
   }

   return $posts;

}
```